Existence of analytic continuation on a punctured disk
Let $D$ denote the open unit disk centered in origin in the complex plane. Let $(f,D)$ be a function element. Does this function element have an analytic continuation to a function defined on the punctured unit disk, where the origin is removed, such that it has a non-removable singularity at the origin?
My attempt is as follows. Assume it has an analytic continuation called $g$ which satisfies the above condition. Then g and f are equal on a set that has an accumulation point in the unit disk. Therefore, they should be equal by the identity theorem. However, the origin is a non-removable singularity of g whereas f is holomorphic on $D$, which is a contradiction.
I was wondering if this is correct, and if not, why it isn't, as well as how I find an example.

That is correct. What are your doubts about it?

@MartinR It seems so easy then. So, I thought there might be some subtleties.
